# OpenID connect plugin uninstall button is disappeared

Tags: php, openid-connect, moodle

I have installed the [openID](https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_oidc) connect the plugin to connect Azure AD in my moodle site. Now I want to uninstall the plugin. But uninstall button is not appearing. I have already checked all dependencies and removed them. But still, uninstall is not there.

[real environment example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1zKu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if any users are using the plugin.

Go to Site admin > Users > Browse list of users

Or direct to `/admin/user.php`

Under the filter click "show more" then choose "Authentication" = "OpenID Connect"

If there are users with that authentication method, then you will need to edit the user and change the value to something else eg: manual.